# Extend C Drive while my C Drive format is GPT and my other partitions are in MBR?

Tags: windows, mbr, gpt

The question is how do I extend my C: drive while my C: drive format is GPT and my other drives/partitions format is MBR.

I tried:

1. EaseUS Partition manager
2. AOMEI Partition Manager
3. Disk Management (windows')

but didn't succeed.

Solutions other than Formating/reinstalling Windows again are appreciable.

Here is the image link of my drives. no other drive merged with C: drive:

Actually, I tried to merge C Drive with Disk2 E drive but failed to do that.

[image: Drives Details]

Comment: I don't think that's possible. GPT and MBR are types of *partition table*, there's only one on every physical disk. Please post a screenshot from Windows' *Disk Management*.

Comment: As @gronostaj suggests, you can't have both types on a single disk (and you don't).  D:, S: and E: are on a separate drive.  Where are you expecting to "Extend" your C: drive to exactly?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, I want to Extend Disk1 GPT C drive with Disk2 E Drive
My C drive space is low thats why i want to extend it without reinstalling the windows

Comment: There's something strange going on with your user account.  You should be able to edit your own posts.  Your proposed edit showed up in the edit review queue, which normally means it was attempted using a different user account.  In this case, the user accounts are the same.  Be vigilant for other unusual actions.  It might be necessary to contact the site to get things cleared up.  http://superuser.com/contact

Comment: @fixer1234 I believe it may be because he had two accounts which were merged. The question was originally asked/edited under the other account.

Comment: @CmAdilCh Why do you need to "extend" the drive? You can either move files from C to E, or use E from now on for storing files/installing programs...

Comment: @wysiwyg, Pre installed window on C drive.but it have just 28GB aprox space.i just want to make bigger C drive rather than to install or store programs on other drives.If I go for converting GPT to MBR then i loose window,But If I convert MBR Drives to GPT then may b C drive extend.

Comment: You gain nothing from converting your second disk to GPT toys can't combine your system partition with your second disk

Comment: @Ramhound, well it means no solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with GPT or MBR. Partitions can't span over multiple disks. One disk can hold multiple partitions, but not the other way round.

The *Images* partition doesn't have any drive letter assigned. Unless you have attached it to a NTFS folder, it looks like it's inaccessible. Now, **it may be a recovery partition**, in that case **you should absolutely leave it alone**. The only solution is to buy a bigger disk and clone your current one.

If you're 100% sure you don't need the *Images* partition, you can delete it to recover slightly over 6 GB of space it occupies. Then you'll be able to expand C: drive to that space, but **you'll have to do that without Windows running**, because you can't resize a file system in use. You can for example boot off a Ubuntu flash drive and use GParted to do that.

Comment: Thanks for your response to this question.
Yes Images partition is a recovery partition.Is it possible that i merge the disk 2 to disk 1 ? and if not then last option is to reinstall the window and make partions when installing window. IS it works?

Comment: It's not possible, these are two separate devices. Like totally separate, you could unplug one, drop it in [this machine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sQYPCPB1g3o) and keep the other one working in your computer. It's impossible now, when installing windows and at any other circumstances, just **impossible**. These are two disks and partition must fit on one disk, period.

Comment: It's not two separate devices. It's one device but I don't know how and why it shows two disks.